# Approximation Graph/curve Fitting using Gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I am trying to approximation Graph(curve Fitting) for quadratic equation. I have 4 data File which contain x and y column.I determine coefficient and write each coefficient File for each data File.

```
clk0_h  clk0_h_c  clk0_s  clk0_s_c  clk1_h  clk1_h_c  clk1_s  clk1_s_c 
c coefficient File (As of now I determie manually for generate Graph in python)
```

The Graph I got is:[image]

The gnuplot code is:

```
set title "Approximation Graph"
set term png
set output 'plot.png'
f(x) = a*x*x + b*x + c
fit f(x) 'clk0_h' via 'clk0_h_c'
fit f(x) 'clk1_h' via 'clk1_h_c'
fit f(x) 'clk0_s' via 'clk0_s_c'
fit f(x) 'clk1_s' via 'clk1_s_c'
plot "clk0_h" using 1:2 with lines, f(x), "clk1_h" using 1:2 with lines, f(x), "clk0_s" using 1:2 with lines, f(x), "clk1_s" using 1:2 with lines, f(x)
```

I am trying to approximation graph of each line. But it looks like, it has mixed or overwrite.
I need to create following Graph using gnuplot.I know, I am very far from original graph.
But Can I know, Can be create scatter graph using gnuplot.

In the below graph, dash line represent the approximation ( for sample represent in two only) But In working Graph, we need four approximation line.

[image]

I tried  gnuplot today only and need to create graph also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always fit the same function `f(x)` with different start values, given in the coefficient files. In order to have four different functions, you must also define those four distinct functions:

```
f0_h(x) = a0_h * x**2 + b0_h * x + c0_h
fit f0_h(x) 'clk0_h' via 'clk0_h_c'

f1_h(x) = a1_h * x**2 + b1_h * x + c1_h
fit f1_h(x) 'clk1_h' via 'clk1_h_c'

f0_s(x) = a0_s * x**2 + b0_s * x + c0_s
fit f0_s(x) 'clk0_s' via 'clk0_s_c'

f1_s(x) = a1_s * x**2 + b1_s * x + c1_s
fit f1_s(x) 'clk1_s' via 'clk1_s_c'

set style data lines
plot 'clk0_h' u 1:2, f0_h(x), \
     'clk1_h' u 1:2, f1_h(x), \
     'clk0_s' u 1:2, f0_s(x), \
     'clk1_s' u 1:2, f1_s(x)
```

Accordingly, your coefficient file must also contain different parameter definitions (using `a0_h` etc.).

If you want to keep the coefficient files to have the same format (use only `a`, `b`, and `c`), you can use one function `f(x)` for fitting, and then assign the fitted variables to the concrete functions which are to be plotted:

```
f(x) = a * x**2 + b * x + c
f0_h(x) = a0_h * x**2 + b0_h * x + c0_h
f1_h(x) = a1_h * x**2 + b1_h * x + c1_h
f0_s(x) = a0_s * x**2 + b0_s * x + c0_s
f1_s(x) = a1_s * x**2 + b1_s * x + c1_s

fit f0_h(x) 'clk0_h' via 'clk0_h_c'
a0_h = a; b0_h = b; c0_h = c;

fit f1_h(x) 'clk1_h' via 'clk1_h_c'
a1_h = a; b1_h = b; c1_h = c;

fit f0_s(x) 'clk0_s' via 'clk0_s_c'
a0_s = a; b0_s = b; c0_s = c;

fit f1_s(x) 'clk1_s' via 'clk1_s_c'
a1_s = a; b1_s = b; c1_s = c;

set style data lines
plot 'clk0_h' u 1:2, f0_h(x), \
     'clk1_h' u 1:2, f1_h(x), \
     'clk0_s' u 1:2, f0_s(x), \
     'clk1_s' u 1:2, f1_s(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Can We create scatter graph also in Gnuplot.if Yes Can you give me some idea to generate scatter graph

Comment: Well, the easiest possiblity for a scatter plot is `splot 'data.txt' with points`. If you have some special needs, I would suggest you to ask a new question.

Comment: Really it is ton of thanks when u have very limited time and you got appropriate input